# How can I check if program/package is installed on OS?

Tags: go

I want to check if `dot` package is installed and is executable on current **OS** with **Go**.

My first idea was to check PATH variable for `/dot` string?
Are there any better ways to get executable/installed packages using **Go**?

Any advice will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: If you want to find a binary in the PATH, you need to look for it in the PATH. You can use [`exec.LookPath`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath) or call out to a shell. Any other requirements would be system specific.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a go `package` ?
If so, try to use `go list github.com/some/package`